watchOS SwiftUI background task not working
I'm attempting to create a standalone watchOS app that fetches the prayer timings of my local mosque in JSON format via an API call. I want the app to fetch the prayer timings in the background, but only once per day, at the start of the day (when prayer timings change, i.e., midnight).
I'm trying to implement this using SwiftUI's backgroundTask modifier as explained in the docs and in this WWDC22 video.
I made sure to enable the Background Modes capability, and this is what my app's Info.plist looks like:

However, I've been unable to get it to work. I would appreciate any assistance I can get and feedback for improvements I can make, even with the Info.plist if anything is incorrect about it. Thank you!
This is what I have so far:
//  PrayerTimesCompanionApp.swift
//  PrayerTimesCompanion Watch App

import SwiftUI
import WatchKit

@main
struct PrayerTimesCompanion_Watch_AppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("TIMINGS_REFRESH")) {
            print("Found matching task")
            scheduleNextBackgroundRefresh()
        }
    }
}

// Schedule the next background refresh
func scheduleNextBackgroundRefresh() {
    let today = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: .now)
    if let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today) {
        WKApplication.shared().scheduleBackgroundRefresh(withPreferredDate: tomorrow, userInfo: "TIMINGS_REFRESH" as NSSecureCoding & NSObjectProtocol) { error in
            if error != nil {
                fatalError("*** An error occurred while scheduling the background refresh task. ***")
            }
            print("*** Scheduled! ***")
        }
    }
}

/  ContentView.swift
//  PrayerTimesCompanion Watch App

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var prayerTimeModel = PrayerTimesModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack {
                VStack(spacing: 15) {
                    // Table Header
                    HStack {
                        Text("Prayer")
                            .bold()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // Align to the left
                        Text("Iqamah")
                            .bold()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing) // Align to the right
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    // Table Rows (5 prayers)
                    ForEach(prayerTimeModel.prayerTimes.data.iqamah, id: \.date) { iqamah in
                        rowView(prayer: "Fajr", time: iqamah.fajr)
                        rowView(prayer: "Zuhr", time: iqamah.zuhr)
                        rowView(prayer: "Asr", time: iqamah.asr)
                        rowView(prayer: "Maghrib", time: iqamah.maghrib)
                        rowView(prayer: "Isha", time: iqamah.isha)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .padding()
            .onAppear {
                prayerTimeModel.fetch()
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
    
    func rowView(prayer: String, time: String) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Text(prayer)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            Text(time)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

//  PrayerTimesModel.swift
//  PrayerTimesCompanion Watch App

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

// Main struct for the response
struct PrayerTimesResponse: Codable {
    let status: String
    var data: SalahData
    let message: [String]
}

// Struct for the data section
struct SalahData: Codable {
    var salah: [Salah]
    var iqamah: [Iqamah]
}

// Struct for Salah times
struct Salah: Codable {
    let date: String
    let hijriDate: String
    let hijriMonth: String
    let day: String
    var fajr: String
    let sunrise: String
    var zuhr: String
    var asr: String
    var maghrib: String
    var isha: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date, hijriDate = "hijri_date", hijriMonth = "hijri_month", day, fajr, sunrise, zuhr, asr, maghrib, isha
    }
}

// Struct for Iqamah times
struct Iqamah: Codable {
    let date: String
    var fajr: String
    var zuhr: String
    var asr: String
    var maghrib: String
    var isha: String
    let jummah1: String
    let jummah2: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date, fajr, zuhr, asr, maghrib, isha, jummah1 = "jummah1", jummah2 = "jummah2"
    }
}


class PrayerTimesModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var prayerTimes: PrayerTimesResponse = PrayerTimesResponse(
        status: "Unknown",
        data: SalahData(
            salah: [Salah(date: "", hijriDate: "", hijriMonth: "", day: "", fajr: "", sunrise: "", zuhr: "", asr: "", maghrib: "", isha: "")],
            iqamah: [Iqamah(date: "", fajr: "", zuhr: "", asr: "", maghrib: "", isha: "", jummah1: "", jummah2: "")]),
        message: ["No data available"]
    )
    
    // fetches the local mosque's prayer timings via an API call
    func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://masjidal.com/api/v1/time/range?masjid_id=3OA87VLp") else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [self] data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            // Convert to JSON
            do {
                var prayerTimes = try JSONDecoder().decode(PrayerTimesResponse.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.prayerTimes = prayerTimes
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

I've looked through Apple Developer docs and WWDC videos as mentioned above, as well as other online materials and video tutorials on YouTube, but couldn't really find any up-to-date material (other than Apple's docs and resources) that involves using SwiftUI's backgroundTask modifier to implement background refresh.
